# Alamofire 4/Swift: progress handler does not offer bytesRead and totalBytesRead anymore?

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire

Recently, I am trying to migrate to Swift 3, which means I will also need to use Alamofire 4.

In Alamofire 3, the progress handler offers access to bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead, however in Alamofire 4, it seems that the handler only has one argument "progress", which only allows me to see the "fractionCompleted". But I will need the bytesRead and totalBytesRead for UILabel's texts. I wonder is it possible for me to get these two values? Thanks a lot!

**Modification:**

Just had a look at the Progress class, and found that there are `completedUnitCount`, `totalUnitCount`, which seem to be the alternative for totalBytesRead and bytesRead. Not sure if I am on the right track?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly, `totalUnitCount` and `completedUnitCount` have the same meaning as `totalBytesExpectedToRead` vs. `totalBytesRead`.
`bytesRead` was a value of an amount incremented (in each iteration) to the totalBytesRead value.

Now the added `fractionCompleted` is already a **ratio** in type of `Double`, so it is useful when used as a value for a progress bar, for example.

I've tested several `Progress` values so this is the code (tested on file about 600 kB in size):

```
.downloadProgress { progress in
     print("fractionCompleted: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")                
     print("completedUnit: \(progress.completedUnitCount)")
     print("totalUnitCount: \(progress.totalUnitCount)")
}
```

... outputs following (I've chosen first 3 iterations from the debug console):

> ```
> fractionCompleted: 0.104675046718523 
> completedUnit: 65536 
> totalUnitCount: 626090
>
> fractionCompleted: 0.209350093437046 
> completedUnit: 131072 
> totalUnitCount: 626090
>
> fractionCompleted: 0.314025140155569 
> completedUnit: 196608 
> totalUnitCount: 626090
>
> ...
> ```

Comment: How can use it in Progress bar??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can rely on `completedUnitCount` and `totalUnitCount` if you're doing a single download/upload task (without subtasks)

From Alamofire 4 doc:

> If the receiver NSProgress object is a "leaf progress" (no children),
>   then the fractionCompleted is generally completedUnitCount /
>   totalUnitCount. If the receiver NSProgress has children, the
>   fractionCompleted will reflect progress made in child objects in
>   addition to its own completedUnitCount. As children finish, the
>   completedUnitCount of the parent will be updated.